# Logon failed issue after report deployment

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    rprt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/report/CrystalReport2.rpt"));
    DataSet ds = obj.Getds("rpt_details");
    rprt.SetDataSource(ds);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rprt;
    Session["ReportDocument"] = rprt;
}
```

On localhost, the report runs properly. But once deployed to the server it gives this error:

> Logon failed. Details: mscorlib : The device is not ready. Error in File C:\Windows\TEMP\CrystalReport2 {BAC2FF3C-45D2-47FC-9AED-7FD5B8D2CC5E}.rpt: Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters.

I deployed and published all files, including `datatable1.xsd` and the files folder.

Answer (score 0):

look in your rpt file and make sure you provide a user name and password for the database connection or add the database user credentials to your code and pass then from the web.config